# can skype uri get my contact list?

Tags: javascript, web, uri, skype

I'm using this uri request:

```
skype:userid?call
```

and was wondering if there was a way i could request my contact list...

```
skype:myid?getcontactlist
```

because the script seems to be accessing my contacts list so this should be easy!

Been on the net all day I can't find a javascript php api (for web development).

Here is a handy piece of code that Im working on:

```
var skype;
$('#area').append('<div id="skype"class="box"><div>'+
                  '<img src="M/skype.png"/><br>'+
                  '<input id="skypeid"type="text"/>'+
                  '<div id="skypebutton"></div>'+
                  '</div></div>');


$('#skypeid').bind('keyup',function(){
    skype='<a href="skype:'+$(this).val()+'?call"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/smallclassic/'+$(this).val()+'" style="border: none;" width="114" height="20" alt="My status" /></a>';
    $('#skypebutton').html(skype);
    });
```

and the script provided by skype:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean you want to fetch the contact list into your JavaScript? That's unlikely to be possible - it would be a major privacy leak.

Comment: why? examples: facebook, twitter, linkedin

Comment: why is this not a data leak?... FB.Data.query("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())); it's the same.

Comment: you have to grant the app permission to do that though? Granted, Skype could do the same thing... no idea whether such an API exists

Comment: Would need this to. The new api would be pretty useless if there is no way of getting data (especially the contact list). How would the user know whats the skype name he would like to call. Any hints out there?